# Array with foreach loop codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Trying to arrange the values in array with mentioned format:

```
 $fields = array(
    'first_name' => array(
              'type' => 'varchar',
               'constraint' => 100,
     ),
     'last_name' => array(
             'type' => 'varchar',
               'constraint' => 100
      ),
      'street_address' => array(
               'type' => 'varchar',
               'constraint' => 200
   ),
 );
```

My code gives error:

```
$fields = array(
  foreach ($this->input->post('fields') as $selectedOption){

                echo $str= $selectedOption."\n";
                $this->load->model('custom_field', '', TRUE);   
                $recordDetails = $this->custom_field->getRecordDetails($str);
                $result = json_decode(json_encode($recordDetails[0]), true);
                 $result['columnName'] = array(
                      'type' => $result['fieldType'],
                       'constraint' => $result['fieldLimit']
                    ),
             }
 );
```

If anyone can help than please!
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error? How come you are initializing an array and within the initialization you are performing a foreach? Please give an example on what you want the result to look like.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to accomplish:

```
$fields = array();
foreach ($this->input->post('fields') as $selectedOption){
            echo $str= $selectedOption."\n";
            $this->load->model('custom_field', '', TRUE);   
            $recordDetails = $this->custom_field->getRecordDetails($str);
            $result = json_decode(json_encode($recordDetails[0]), true);
            $fields['columnName'] = array(
                  'type' => $result['fieldType'],
                   'constraint' => $result['fieldLimit']
                );
}
```